# Specifying y_label in Pandas plot()

Tags: pandas, plot

I want to specify y_label in the following Pandas plot function, but it seems that the syntax is not correct.

```
row = df.iloc[0].astype(int)
row.value_counts().reindex().plot(ylabel='something').bar()
```

because the error is

```
bar() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'height'
```

If I use `row.value_counts().reindex().plot().bar()`, there is no problem, but there no y_label too. How can I fix that?

Comment: does `row.value_counts().reindex().plot(kind='bar')` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
ax = row.value_counts().reindex().plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_ylabel("something")
```

Comment: Also `row.value_counts().reindex().plot(kind='bar',ylabel='something')` works